# How can I make \lstinline function normally inside math mode?

Tags: math-mode, listings, inline

`\lstinline` of the `listings` package doesn't work in math mode. When I try to use it, I get the error that `\ttfamily` is invalid in math mode.

However, when reasoning about program semantics, it is often necessary to put snippets of program code inside mathematical constructs and, ideally, this would be done with `\lstinline` in order to keep a consistent style between inline snippets and larger code blocks.

There are several ad-hoc case-by-case solutions, of course. I've been able to make `\lstinline` work within a `\text` command, being extra careful to escape certain characters. Sometimes I don't use `\lstinline` at all and format the code snippet by hand. Neither is really convenient.

Is there a generally applicable solution? Ideally I could just use `\lstinline` in math mode (well, its `\lstMakeShortInline` shortcut anyway) without any error. I do occasionally use `mathescape` inside code snippets. Having that still work would be nice, but is not essential.

Comment: just a wild guess ... if you're using `amsmath`, try wrapping the `lstinline` string in `\text{...}`.  (i don't use `listings`, so this is totally off the wall.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Like I said, using `\text` sometimes works (I think the `listings` developer(s) had a hard time making that sort of thing work, actually). But then I need to escape special characters. All in all, it's more verbose than I'd like. My question is: can I make `\lstinline` work as is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not need the resizing feature of `\text` and a simple `\hbox` (`\mbox`) suffices, then the following redefinition patches the first `\bgroup` to add `\hbox` in math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\newcommand*{\SavedLstInline}{}
\LetLtxMacro\SavedLstInline\lstinline
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\lstinline}{%
  \ifmmode
    \let\SavedBGroup\bgroup
    \def\bgroup{%
      \let\bgroup\SavedBGroup
      \hbox\bgroup
    }%
  \fi
  \SavedLstInline
}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\centering
Text: \lstinline|\foo%&$bar|
\[
  x = \lstinline|\foo%&$bar|
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Patching via package `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname \string\lstinline\endcsname{%
  \leavevmode
  \bgroup
}{%
  \leavevmode
  \ifmmode\hbox\fi
  \bgroup
}{}{%
  \typeout{Patching of \string\lstinline\space failed!}%
}

\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\centering
Text: \lstinline|\foo%&$bar|
\[
  x = \lstinline|\foo%&$bar|
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That will do just fine, thanks! :-) I've been trying to patch the command too, but my way was very convoluted (and didn't work). This is quite elegant.

Comment: The package code has a comment right at the line we're patching: `% \hbox\bgroup --> \bgroup`. Does this mean they once had an `\hbox` there but removed it? :-) I guess with the `\hbox` there, inline code cannot wrap around a newline (but no worries, I don't need that).

Comment: Is there a similar way to patch mintinline?  (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555462/how-can-i-patch-mintinline-to-work-with-breaklines-and-mathmode)

Comment: Remark, refer to [math mode - lstinline in mathmode with correct font size - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/661742/lstinline-in-mathmode-with-correct-font-size?noredirect=1&lq=1) for ways to use the functionality of `\text` (i.e. correct font size).