# Inline listing in ams environment drops space before mathescape

Tags: math-mode, spacing, listings, amsmath

In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127018/83257 there is a patch to make inline listings work in math mode. When using this together with listings' `mathescape` option, the space after a math escape is dropped in ams environments. The space is preserved in regular math blocks like `\[ ... \]`. I hope someone can help me fix this, I don't have the knowledge to figure it out by myself. A MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{mathescape,keepspaces}

%% patch from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127018/83257
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname \string\lstinline\endcsname{%
  \leavevmode
  \bgroup
}{%
  \leavevmode
  \ifmmode\hbox\fi
  \bgroup
}{}{%
  \typeout{Patching of \string\lstinline\space failed!}%
}
%% end of patch

\begin{document}

Space before mathescape preserved:
\[
    \lstinline|ifz $x$ then E$_2$ else E$_3$|
\]

Space before mathescape dropped:
\begin{align*}
    \lstinline|ifz $x$ then E$_2$ else E$_3$|
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Discovered listings' `keepspaces` option solves part of the problem. Spaces after the mathe scape are not preserved, but spaces before are still dropped.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an option provided by the `listings` package (and found and reported by the author) easily solved the problem.  **oops**, voted too soon; the question has been restated -- a problem still exists, just not the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not affect just the `amsmath` environments. This minimal example also exhibits the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{mathescape,keepspaces}

\newcommand\identity[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
  \lstinline!let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$!

  \identity{\lstinline!let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$!}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this output

[image: Example 1]

In the [`listings` documentation](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), Section 6.1, it says that if `\lstinline` is used inside an argument, some spaces have to be protected by escaping them with `\`. Although it doesn't mention escaping to math mode, it seems to be one of the cases. Escaping spaces with `\` fixes the problem for both `align` and my example.

```
  \lstinline!let $v_1$ = 10 in $v_1$ + $v_2$!

  \identity{\lstinline!let\ $v_1$ = 10 in\ $v_1$ +\ $v_2$!}
  \begin{align}
    \lstinline!let\ $v_1$ = 10 in\ $v_1$ +\ $v_2$!
  \end{align}
```

[image: Example 2]

It is mighty annoying to have to do this, especially since, e.g., changing `align` to `equation` will show the backslashes and they have to be removed again.

Comment: Indeed, as soon as the listings command is used as an argument somewhere, it seems quite brittle. I've switched to `minted`, which seems much more robust, although it is more involved to setup.