# lstinputlisting environment in equation- and math environment?

Tags: automation, import, parameters

I am trying to semi-automatically import multiple parameters/variables from an excel (via .txt) file into both equation environments and $$ = math environments in (share)latex.

It is semi-automattically because I still need to manually import a .txt file into (share)latex.

My approach consists of the following e.g. `test.txt` file:

```
2: The old conversion coefficient k_{roe,Sv}
9.329664
4: The new conversion coefficient {K_{roe,Sv}}_{new}
0
6: r_{worst}
817278.6
8: r_{best}
81727.9
```

And the numbers are imported with the following/similair latex lines:

```
\item $K_{sh} = \lstinputlisting[firstline=28,lastline=28]{data_input/test.txt}$
```

Where the datapoint/number is selected by varying the line number (e.g. 4 to 6) in both `firstline=4` and `lastline=4`.

It works fine in the normal (share)latex environment. However, if I apply the command in a $$ environment, I get the following error:

`missing $ inserted`

and if I add an extra $ sign after the command e.g.

```
\item $K_{sh} = \lstinputlisting[firstline=28,lastline=28]{data_input/test.txt}$$
```

it still get that same error.

So I tried putting it in a math Environment with:

```
\item $K_{sh} = \ensuremath{\lstinputlisting[firstline=28,lastline=28]{data_input/test.txt}}$
```

and

```
\item $K_{sh} = \ensuremath{\lstinputlisting[firstline=28,lastline=28]{data_input/test.txt}}$$
```

As was suggested in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239585/how-can-i-write-a-macro-which-enters-math-mode-when-called-in-text-mode-but-when). However, the missing $ error still remains.

I fear it might be a double question, but with the searchterms known to me, I have not been able to find a working solution. Would you know the solution?

As to comply with BambOo's tip/comment, I have created the following MWE in which the `K_{sh..` lines are tested individually by commenting the other 3 `K_{sh..` lines out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}


\title{MWE import data}
\author{A.T.}
\date{April 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\ensuremath{test} %Testing whether the \ensuremath command requires a package; it does not.

% $K_{sh} = \lstinputlisting[firstline=2,lastline=2]{test.txt}$

% $K_{sh} = \lstinputlisting[firstline=2,lastline=2]{test.txt}$$

% $K_{sh} = \ensuremath{\lstinputlisting[firstline=2,lastline=2]{test.txt}}$

$K_{sh} = \ensuremath{\lstinputlisting[firstline=2,lastline=2]{test.txt}}$$



\end{document}
```

It makes use of the following `test.txt` file in the same folder as `main.tex`:

```
2: The old conversion coefficient k_{roe,Sv}
9.329664
4: The new conversion coefficient {K_{roe,Sv}}_{new}
0
6: r_{worst}
817278.6
8: r_{best}
81727.9
```

I did not find out whether it is convention to post the MWE here as code, or whether to link to an external file, I guess w.r.t. availability reduction when the external source goes off line, code is preferred even though it takes more time to recreate.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Possibly related post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127010/how-can-i-make-lstinline-function-normally-inside-math-mode?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you Bobyandbob! And the related post indeed appears to answer this question. I think this is still a valuable posts for people trying to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Tahnk you @BambOo, I think I added a correct MWE for completeness. I was not aware that the concept that distinguishes itself from an incomplete attempt to share what you are doing,  had a name, so I learned that today, it will improve my interaction on the whole site. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Have a look at [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself with the process here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure `listings` is the best tool for the job:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
2: The old conversion coefficient k_{roe,Sv}
9.329664
4: The new conversion coefficient {K_{roe,Sv}}_{new}
0
6: r_{worst}
817278.6
8: r_{best}
81727.9
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool,siunitx}

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{data}{\jobname.txt}
\newcommand{\mydatavalue}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \dtlgetrow{data}{#1}%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\temp}{1}%
  \num{\temp}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $K_{sh} = \mydatavalue{2}$

\item $K_{sh} = \mydatavalue{4}$

\item $K_{sh} = \mydatavalue{6}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

There is possibly a better method with `datatool`.

[image]

A different implementation, as `datatool` may seem overkill.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
2: The old conversion coefficient k_{roe,Sv}
9.329664
4: The new conversion coefficient {K_{roe,Sv}}_{new}
0
6: r_{worst}
817278.6
8: r_{best}
81727.9
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\loaddatafile}{O{default}m}
 {% #1 = symbolic name, #2 = file name
  \at_datafile_load:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getdataline}{O{default}m}
 {
  \seq_item:cn { g_at_datafile_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\ior_new:N \g_at_datafile_stream

\cs_new_protected:Nn \at_datafile_load:nn
 {
  \seq_gclear_new:c { g_at_datafile_#1_seq }
  \ior_open:Nn \g_at_datafile_stream { #2 }
  \ior_map_inline:Nn \g_at_datafile_stream
   {
    \seq_put_right:cx { g_at_datafile_#1_seq } { \tl_trim_spaces:n { ##1 } }
   }
  \ior_close:N \g_at_datafile_stream
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\loaddatafile{\jobname.txt}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $K_{sh} = \num{\getdataline{2}}$

\item $K_{sh} = \num{\getdataline{4}}$

\item $K_{sh} = \num{\getdataline{6}}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @egreg, that was exactly what I have been trying to build! I noticed if I add the txt the way you did it, to the (share)latex, that the values do not get updated in a "normal"(not "fast") recompile. But when I upload the `test.txt` manually as a separate file to the same folder as `main.text` it does. You made my day! It allows me to work more effectively through iterations. (I can not upvote you nor the comments yet since I do not have enough reputation, yet.)

Comment: @a.t. I used `filecontents` just to make the example self-contained. Use an independent file with the name you prefer.

Comment: Ah, thank you, convenient. I was actually curious how it gets processed with that method and why it then does not synchronize, but I will investigate that at a later point in time.

Answer (score 0):

So for future users running into the same problem, here is the implementation of the solution that @egreg gave, (including a script to export your excel parameters to .txt for your convenience):

First add package to main.tex:

```
\usepackage{datatool,siunitx} %To import data from a textfile
```

Then

```
%Make own commands to import variable parameters in main.tex:

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{data0}{data_input/excel_output_L.txt}
\newcommand{\inl}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \dtlgetrow{data0}{#1}%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\temp}{1}%
  \num{\temp}%
  \endgroup
}

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{data1}{data_input/excel_output_M_G.txt}
\newcommand{\inmg}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \dtlgetrow{data1}{#1}%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\temp}{1}%
  \num{\temp}%
  \endgroup
}

\DTLloaddb[noheader]{data2}{data_input/excel_output_H.txt}
\newcommand{\inh}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \dtlgetrow{data2}{#1}%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\temp}{1}%
  \num{\temp}%
  \endgroup
}
```

After that add txt files to folder: data_input in the (share)latex folder

Proceed by calling the parameters (e.g. the number in line 6 of excel_output_H.txt) with:

```
\inmg{6}
```

(Which can be called in a math environment inside a itemize/enumerate environment:

```
\item $K_{shielding} = \inmg{6}$
```

And for completeness This is the code that exports the excel columns E3:E100 to .txt for the 3 sheets in "the" workbook:

```
Sub export_to_txt()
Dim myFile As String, rng As Range, cellValue As Variant, i As Integer, j As Integer
For nr_sheets = 1 To 3
    If nr_sheets = 1 Then
        sheetname = "L"
    End If
    If nr_sheets = 2 Then
        sheetname = "M_G"
    End If
    If nr_sheets = 3 Then
        sheetname = "H"
    End If
    myFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\excel_output_" & sheetname & ".txt"
    'MsgBox (sheetname)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Activate
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetname).Range("E3:E100")
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To rng.Columns.Count
    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
    If j = rng.Columns.Count Then
        Write #1, cellValue
    Else
        Write #1, cellValue,
    End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Close #1
Next nr_sheets
End Sub
```